# Fetch record with foreign key in laravel5

Tags: foreign-keys, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5. I have two tables named **cars** and **providers**. There is a foreign key in **cars** table named *provider_id* of **provider** table.

My database schema as follows-

```
Schema::create('cars', function(Blueprint $table)
{
   $table->increments('id');
   $table->integer('provider_id')->unsigned();
   $table->foreign('provider_id')->references('id')->on('providers')->onDelete('restrict');
});

Schema::create('providers', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('company_name');
});
```

Now, I want to fetch cars information as well as provider info of that particular id.

Comment: you can use joins, you are using eloquent or query builder? answer me and I will show you  a code to take out both provider and car info.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships)

Inside your Car model, create a provider method:

```
public function provider()
{
    return this->belongsTo(\App\Provider);
}
```

Then, you can do something like:

```
$car = \App\Car::find(id);
```

And access the provider this way:

```
$car->provider();
```

Also, inside your provider model, add this:

```
public function cars()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Car);
}
```

And you'll be able to access all cars from a particular provider.